# Future returned by Slick run method completes successfully before rows have been inserted

Tags: postgresql, scala, slick-3.0

I am working a Scala app using Slick and PostgreSQL for storage. I have a method `foo` which reads data from a CSV file and inserts about 10,000 rows into the database. After the Future of the row insertion action completes, another method `bar` is called which retrieves these rows from the database and performs some actions on them. This is where the problem lies: no rows are actually retrieved from the database, as no rows have been inserted by the time the Future completes.

From what I could gather while looking for an answer and at the official documentation, the Future is not supposed to complete before the insert statement is successfully executed. If I add the following code `Thread.sleep(30000)` to `bar`, allowing the insert statement to be executed first, the methods provide the expected result. Now, for obvious reasons I would rather not do that, so I am looking for alternatives.

The following diagram illustrates the program flow once initial method `doStuff` is called:

[image: The program flow diagram]

`doStuff` calls `foo` which loads the data and stores it in the database, before returning a Future. In `doStuff` this Future is then mapped and a call to `bar` is made. `bar` bar retrieves the rows from the database and processes them. However, since no rows have been inserted at the point where `bar` is called, no data is processed.

The `doStuff` method:

```
def doStuff(csvFile: File): Future[Unit] = {
  fooService.foo(csvFile)
    .map(_ => {
      csvFile.delete()
      barService.bar()
    })
}
```

The `foo` method:

```
def foo(file: File) Future[Unit] = {
  val reader = CSVReader.open(file)
  fooStorage.truncateFooData().map(_ => {
    val foos = for (line <- reader.iterator if
    line.head != "bad1" &&
      line.head !="bad2")
      yield parseFooData(line)
    fooStorage.saveFooDataBulk(foos.toSeq)
  })
}
```

How I am using Slick to insert the rows:

```
override def saveFooDataBulk(fooSeq: Seq[Foo]): Future[Seq[Foo]] =
  db.run(DBIO.seq(fooQuery ++= fooSeq)).map(_ => fooSeq)
```

I am expecting `bar` to be called once all the rows have been inserted into the database and not sooner, however, currently the Future from Slick completes too soon. In case it's relevant: the `doStuff` method is called when a request is sent to an Akka Http endpoint. The application and the database are running in two different docker containers. What am I doing wrong?

<sub>Also I can't get over how appropriate the username I picked a year and a half ago is now.</sub>

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Replace `map` by `flatMap` in the `def foo`. Otherwise, it will start a `Future[Seq[Foo]]`, then immediately return a `()`, which is then discarded by your `doStuff`. Something like this:

```
fooStorage
  .truncateFooData()
  .flatMap(_ => {
    /* stuff... */
    fooStorage.saveFooDataBulk(foo.toSeq)
  })
  .map(_ => ())
```

I didn't test it, but in any case, starting some `Future`s in the middle of another `Future.map` and then immediately returning an `()` doesn't feel quite right.

Comment: I think I see what the problem was. The Future from truncateFooData completes and is mapped with the supplied lambda. However, I naively expected that the map in doStuff would wait for the saveFooDataBulk Future, but that Future was the result of the outer Future, which would be completed much sooner. By using flatMap, the inner Future must be completed as well. Is that correct?
I am very new to Scala, so perhaps there is a cleaner way of achieving what I'm trying to achieve?

Comment: @SlickVick I think your understanding is essentially correct. Maybe one might want to move the code with `iterator`-related stuff out of the `Future`-related stuff, and then write a shorter & clearer `for`-comprehension that involves only `Future`'s `map` and `flatMap`. I would probably reorder and reindent the whole thing slightly differently, but the principle wouldn't change much.